# Run pipeline on user provided agent or on default pool if not provided

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to add a parameter to my pipeline to un it on a specific Build Agent only if user provided it. If user didn't provide it then use any agent from default pool.
As for now I can't find a way to do in in Azure Devops yaml configuration.

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['agentName'], '') }}:  
    agent: $(defaultAgentList)
  ${{ if ne(variables['agentName'], '') }}:
    agent: ''
pool: 
  name: buildAgents
  ${{ if ne(variables['agentList'], '') }}:
    demands:
    - Agent.Name -eqals variables.agent
trigger: none
jobs:
- job: run_tests
  timeoutInMinutes: 60
  displayName: Log success
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      echo "success!"
    displayName: 'Test custom agent'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You mixed two kind of expression.

This part `variables['agentList']` would be properly evaluated at runtime.

But expression `${{ }}` is evaluated at compile time. At this time `agentList` would be empty.

But you can try to use parameters:

```
parameters:
  - name: 'agentName'
    type: string
    default: ''

jobs:
  - job: 'Example'
    pool:
      ${{ if ne(parameters.agentName, '') }}:
        name: buildAgents
        demands:
         - Agent.Name -eqals ${{ parameters.agentName }}
      ${{ else }}:
        name: buildAgents
    steps:
      - script: example
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. For anyone else I would like to also emphasize that Azure allows template expressions for pool only if it is specified for job. If it is specified on top level you'll get error `template expression is not allowed in this context`.

Comment: @Mykola could you consider upvorting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Comment: Sure, I wasn't able to do so yesterday as I had too low reputation but now it seems to work, thanks again!